# Merge the split file vs Original compressed file

Tags: ubuntu, tar, compression, split

On Ubuntu 22.04,
I found these 2 methods will get different sha256 of archive_tgz

```
tar czf /a/archive_tgz . 

tar czf /dev/stdout . | split -d -b 200M - /a/archive. && cat /a/archive.* > /a/archive_tgz
```

Is it normal or about block size of file?
What's the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is because modification time of `.` changes *and it is included in the tar file* (`tar czf archive.tgz .` updates `.`).

```bash
tar czf /dev/stdout . | sha256sum
```

and

```bash
tar czf archive.tgz .
sha256sum archive.tgz
```

already give different hashes (without `split`). It also warns `tar: .: file changed as we read it`.

Writing to a different directory so `.`'s modification time is unchanged gives the same hash.

```bash
tar czf ../archive.tgz .
sha256sum ../archive.tgz
```

---

You can also verify it isn't `split`'s problem by comparing the hashes:

```bash
tar czf single-archive.tgz .

split -d -b 200M - single-archive.tgz archive. && cat archive.* >archive-combined.tgz

md5sum single-archive.tgz
md5sum archive-combined.tgz
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe my problem clearly and I modify it.
I do write them to a different directory.

Comment: @Azreal it is because it is padded with null bytes. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/747693/272821 for details.

Comment: You can fix by using `-` instead of `/dev/stdout`.