# Why does tar's handling of stdout and - differ?

Tags: linux, shell, tar, buffer

After a [comment from OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747613/merge-the-split-file-vs-original-compressed-file/747616#comment1421974_747616), I discovered that `/dev/stdout` gives blocks of 10 KiB even after disabling buffering, but `-` does not. Why is this? I could not find anything regarding this in `man tar` nor `man stdout`.

Note that `/dev/stdout` goes to `00002800`, not `000000a1`. The output is correct, except is padded with null bytes.

```
> mkdir -p /tmp/747613
> cd /tmp/747613
> echo 747613 > file.txt

> tar czf /tmp/archive_tgz .
> hd /tmp/archive_tgz
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 ed d1 41 0a c2 30  |............A..0|
00000010  10 85 e1 ac 3d 45 4e 90  66 9a 49 72 9e 2e 22 08  |....=EN.f.Ir..".|
00000020  ea a2 46 f0 f8 a6 8b a2  9b 76 21 04 11 ff 6f f3  |..F......v!...o.|
00000030  20 33 90 81 e7 06 d3 9d  6f 72 8e 4b 4a 8e fe 3d  | 3......or.KJ..=|
00000040  57 46 54 43 6c 8f 69 6c  7b 22 da c6 36 f6 3f cd  |WFTCl.il{"..6.?.|
00000050  98 fb ad 4e b3 b5 2d cb  7c 9d 2e 65 7b 6f 7f fe  |...N..-.|..e{o..|
00000060  a3 dc 70 3c 9d 8b ab 8f  da ef 8f a5 e0 94 74 a7  |..p<..........t.|
00000070  ff bc f6 2f 41 a5 f5 1f  64 14 63 7d bf 93 5e fe  |.../A...d.c}..^.|
00000080  bc ff ac 39 49 38 7c fb  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...9I8|.........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 78  02 88 2a 27 ac 00 28 00  |.......x..*'..(.|
*
000000a1

> tar czf /dev/stdout . | hd
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 ed d1 41 0a c2 30  |............A..0|
00000010  10 85 e1 ac 3d 45 4e 90  66 9a 49 72 9e 2e 22 08  |....=EN.f.Ir..".|
00000020  ea a2 46 f0 f8 a6 8b a2  9b 76 21 04 11 ff 6f f3  |..F......v!...o.|
00000030  20 33 90 81 e7 06 d3 9d  6f 72 8e 4b 4a 8e fe 3d  | 3......or.KJ..=|
00000040  57 46 54 43 6c 8f 69 6c  7b 22 da c6 36 f6 3f cd  |WFTCl.il{"..6.?.|
00000050  98 fb ad 4e b3 b5 2d cb  7c 9d 2e 65 7b 6f 7f fe  |...N..-.|..e{o..|
00000060  a3 dc 70 3c 9d 8b ab 8f  da ef 8f a5 e0 94 74 a7  |..p<..........t.|
00000070  ff bc f6 2f 41 a5 f5 1f  64 14 63 7d bf 93 5e fe  |.../A...d.c}..^.|
00000080  bc ff ac 39 49 38 7c fb  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...9I8|.........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 78  02 88 2a 27 ac 00 28 00  |.......x..*'..(.|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002800

> # Even with buffering disabled
> stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 tar czf /dev/stdout . | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 hd
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 ed d1 41 0a c2 30  |............A..0|
00000010  10 85 e1 ac 3d 45 4e 90  66 9a 49 72 9e 2e 22 08  |....=EN.f.Ir..".|
00000020  ea a2 46 f0 f8 a6 8b a2  9b 76 21 04 11 ff 6f f3  |..F......v!...o.|
00000030  20 33 90 81 e7 06 d3 9d  6f 72 8e 4b 4a 8e fe 3d  | 3......or.KJ..=|
00000040  57 46 54 43 6c 8f 69 6c  7b 22 da c6 36 f6 3f cd  |WFTCl.il{"..6.?.|
00000050  98 fb ad 4e b3 b5 2d cb  7c 9d 2e 65 7b 6f 7f fe  |...N..-.|..e{o..|
00000060  a3 dc 70 3c 9d 8b ab 8f  da ef 8f a5 e0 94 74 a7  |..p<..........t.|
00000070  ff bc f6 2f 41 a5 f5 1f  64 14 63 7d bf 93 5e fe  |.../A...d.c}..^.|
00000080  bc ff ac 39 49 38 7c fb  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...9I8|.........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 78  02 88 2a 27 ac 00 28 00  |.......x..*'..(.|
000000a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00002800

> # Works fine (- means stdout)
> tar czf - . | hd
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 ed d1 41 0a c2 30  |............A..0|
00000010  10 85 e1 ac 3d 45 4e 90  66 9a 49 72 9e 2e 22 08  |....=EN.f.Ir..".|
00000020  ea a2 46 f0 f8 a6 8b a2  9b 76 21 04 11 ff 6f f3  |..F......v!...o.|
00000030  20 33 90 81 e7 06 d3 9d  6f 72 8e 4b 4a 8e fe 3d  | 3......or.KJ..=|
00000040  57 46 54 43 6c 8f 69 6c  7b 22 da c6 36 f6 3f cd  |WFTCl.il{"..6.?.|
00000050  98 fb ad 4e b3 b5 2d cb  7c 9d 2e 65 7b 6f 7f fe  |...N..-.|..e{o..|
00000060  a3 dc 70 3c 9d 8b ab 8f  da ef 8f a5 e0 94 74 a7  |..p<..........t.|
00000070  ff bc f6 2f 41 a5 f5 1f  64 14 63 7d bf 93 5e fe  |.../A...d.c}..^.|
00000080  bc ff ac 39 49 38 7c fb  0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |...9I8|.........|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 1f 78  02 88 2a 27 ac 00 28 00  |.......x..*'..(.|
*
000000a1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference in behaviour comes from `tar`: when writing, it applies a “[blocking factor](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Blocking-Factor.html)”, which by default uses 10240-byte records (that’s 2800 in hexadecimal). This happens even when compressing, which is why some tarballs result in error messages from `gzip` when they are extracted. The behaviour is disabled at the end of the archive when it is written to a regular file, or to standard out (although the manual says it isn’t).

When writing to `/dev/stdout`, `tar` believes it’s writing to a device, and applies its blocking factor. You can verify this by changing the blocking factor:

```
$ tar czfb /dev/stdout 1 . | hd
00000000  1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00  00 03 ed d1 31 0e 83 30  |............1..0|
00000010  0c 05 50 cf 9c 22 27 08  76 b0 e3 f3 74 48 25 24  |..P.."'.v...tH%$|
00000020  26 08 88 e3 03 43 55 c4  00 53 8a 2a fc 16 0f b6  |&....CU..S.*....|
00000030  e4 2f 7d 5f 43 71 b8 52  91 6d 92 0a ee e7 07 10  |./}_Cq.R.m......|
00000040  73 13 31 10 62 04 24 0c  2c e0 a4 7c 34 80 71 c8  |s.1.b.$.,..|4.q.|
00000050  af de 39 18 72 9a d2 c9  dd d5 fe 4f f9 fa dd 76  |..9.r......O...v|
00000060  c9 e7 39 97 fb b1 15 1c  99 4f fa d7 43 ff a4 21  |..9......O..C..!|
00000070  80 c3 72 91 be 1e de bf  b2 46 6a aa bb 63 18 63  |..r......Fj..c.c|
00000080  8c f9 b1 05 02 0c 89 df  00 0a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00000200
```

Comment: Is it safe to always use `--blocking-factor=1`?

Comment: [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Blocking-Factor) is quite specific about the conditions for not doing reblocking. I wonder if it's a bug. One of the conditions listed is usage of compression, and that is still checked, so `tar cf - .` or `tar c .` give different results (wrt reblocking) from `tar czf - .` or `tar cz .`.

Comment: @wjwrpoyob yes, it’s safe, unless you’re writing directly to tape.

Comment: A manual that says "I’ll ask Jean-loup Gailly, by sending a copy of this message to him." is almost certainly some old mailing list post or private e-mail thread copied into documentation.  (-:  From the 1990s, very probably.  The FreeBSD manual calls this out as a bug, by the way: https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tar&sektion=1#BUGS

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly disable blocking factor?